# Elasticsearch CouchDB river bogus chunk size

Tags: java, couchdb, elasticsearch

Sorry, this is a kind of related to another post. Once my CouchDB gets a fair amount of documents in it, ES starts throwing errors in the log and doesn't index newer files:

```
[2013-08-19 17:55:08,379][WARN ][river.couchdb            ] [Morning Star] [couchdb][portal_production] failed to read from _changes, throttling....
java.io.IOException: Bogus chunk size
at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.processRaw(ChunkedInputStream.java:319)
at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.readAheadBlocking(ChunkedInputStream.java:572)
at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.readAhead(ChunkedInputStream.java:609)
at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.read(ChunkedInputStream.java:696)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:3052)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:283)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:325)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:177)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:154)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:317)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:382)
at org.elasticsearch.river.couchdb.CouchdbRiver$Slurper.run(CouchdbRiver.java:477)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
[2013-08-19 17:55:13,392][WARN ][river.couchdb            ] [Morning Star] [couchdb][portal_production] failed to read from _changes, throttling....
```

What's the dealio?

## Edit - river status

```
$ curl http://localhost:9200/_river/portal_production/_status?pretty=true 
{
  "_index" : "_river",
  "_type" : "portal_production",
  "_id" : "_status",
  "_version" : 2,
  "exists" : true, "_source" : {"ok":true,"node":{"id":"EVxlLNZ9SrSXYOLS0YBw7w","name":"Shadow Slasher","transport_address":"inet[/192.168.1.106:9300]"}}
}
```

## Edit - River sequence data

Seems pretty low!

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:9200/_river/portal_production/_seq?pretty=true
{
  "_index" : "_river",
  "_type" : "portal_production",
  "_id" : "_seq",
  "_version" : 1,
  "exists" : true, "_source" : {"couchdb":{"last_seq":"4"}}
}
```

My _changes is much bigger, by the way:

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:5984/portal_production/_changes?limit=5
    {"results":[
    {"seq":4,"id":"Ifilter-1","changes":[{"rev":"4-d9c8e771bc345d1182fbe7c2d63f5d00"}]},
    {"seq":7,"id":"Document-2","changes":[{"rev":"1-42f52115c4a5321328be07c490932b61"}]},
    {"seq":10,"id":"Document-4","changes":[{"rev":"1-42f52115c4a5321328be07c490932b61"}]},
    {"seq":13,"id":"Document-6","changes":[{"rev":"1-42f52115c4a5321328be07c490932b61"}]},
    {"seq":16,"id":"Document-8","changes":[{"rev":"1-42f52115c4a5321328be07c490932b61"}]},
    ...
    {"seq":208657,"id":"Document-11295","changes":[{"rev":"8-37cb48660d28bef854b2c31132bc9635"}]},
    {"seq":208661,"id":"Document-11297","changes":[{"rev":"6-daf5c5d557d0fa30b2b08be26582a33c"}]},
    {"seq":208665,"id":"Document-11299","changes":[{"rev":"6-22e57345c2ee5c7aee8b7d664606b874"}]},
    {"seq":208669,"id":"Document-11301","changes":[{"rev":"6-06deee0c3c6705238a8b07e400b2414b"}]},
    {"seq":208673,"id":"Document-11303","changes":[{"rev":"6-86fc60dd8c1d415d42a25a23eb975121"}]},
    {"seq":208677,"id":"Document-11305","changes":[{"rev":"6-6d51a577fdc9013abf64ec4ffbf9eeee"}]},
    {"seq":208683,"id":"Document-11307","changes":[{"rev":"6-726a7835ce390094b9b9e0a91aeb11f0"}]},
    {"seq":208684,"id":"Document-11286","changes":[{"rev":"9-747e63e0304a974cc7db7ff84ae80697"}]}
    ],
    "last_seq":208684}
```

## Edit - Couchdb log

This seems bad:

```
[Thu, 22 Aug 2013 02:49:37 GMT] [info] [<0.340.0>] 127.0.0.1 - - 'GET' /portal_production/_changes?feed=continuous&include_docs=true&heartbeat=10000&since=4 500

[Thu, 22 Aug 2013 02:49:42 GMT] [info] [<0.348.0>] 127.0.0.1 - - 'GET' /portal_production/_changes?feed=continuous&include_docs=true&heartbeat=10000&since=4 200

[Thu, 22 Aug 2013 02:49:42 GMT] [error] [<0.348.0>] Uncaught error in HTTP request: {exit,{ucs,{bad_utf8_character_code}}}

[Thu, 22 Aug 2013 02:49:42 GMT] [info] [<0.348.0>] Stacktrace: [{xmerl_ucs,from_utf8,1},
         {mochijson2,json_encode_string,2},
         {mochijson2,'-json_encode_proplist/2-fun-0-',3},
         {lists,foldl,3},
         {mochijson2,json_encode_proplist,2},
         {mochijson2,'-json_encode_proplist/2-fun-0-',3},
         {lists,foldl,3},
         {mochijson2,json_encode_proplist,2}]
```

Comment: Weird. I know it's in production but any chance that you can grab the exact _changes line the river is blocked at? I think you can get from the river in _status the current seq number.

Comment: I didn't see it, see that above edits. I'm doing some more hunting.

Comment: Sorry. It's in _seq not _status.

Comment: I think I might have some bad character(s) in one of my documents. Going through the _changes stream with the 'since' parameter, I can make couchdb return the error by including 'include_doc=true'. So it's most likely a couchdb error. I'll have an update when it works again.

Comment: Yeah! I suspected something like that. Could you find it.

Comment: Still clearing out bad documents, I think there were a few. Strange that CouchDB allows a PUT on unsupported chars, but not a GET. Weird.

Comment: "Could you find it" -> I meant "Cool you find it" :-)

Answer (score 0):

So I kept deleting documents one by one, and retrying the _changes query with include_doc=true. But I never got to the bottom of it. Reading through some other related issues, imports done on text from Microsoft documents can have some of the funky characters. We're doing something like that, so we dumped the database, and are filtering non-UTF8 characters out. A little painful, but we had too many documents to find where the issue was. So far, no errors on the Elasticsearch side (well, some timeouts, but that is probably another thread).

Answer (score 0):

Are you indexing office documents?
You could use the attachment plugin.

I have a [branch](https://github.com/dadoonet/elasticsearch-river-couchdb/tree/issue/25) not already merged that index couchdb attachments. If you want to test it, I will be happy to get feedback!

Comment: Cool! Well, we're parsing office documents. I know, scary right? So does the code in the branch index the contents of the documents as well? Maybe more of a CouchDB question. I'm sure will actually use CouchDB attachments someday, so we'd be happy to give it a try then!

Comment: Exactly! It index couchdb attachments.

Comment: Hmm, I'll have to play around with this. This could be extremely useful for us!